# Unable to run web application using spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I am trying to run spring boot application with mysql database. I have not added any code. I was just trying to run it but I am getting the error. I am new to the spring boot so pardon me such a dumb question. But I somehow can not figure out why I am not able to run this. This is the log after starting app (I am using IDEA):

```
2018-04-22 19:25:36.252  INFO 19474 --- [           main] com.reminder.EJA.EjaApplication          : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-04-22 19:25:36.333  INFO 19474 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@1a04f701: startup date [Sun Apr 22 19:25:36 CEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-04-22 19:25:36.998  WARN 19474 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor  : Cannot enhance @Configuration bean definition 'com.vaadin.spring.VaadinConfiguration' since its singleton instance has been created too early. The typical cause is a non-static @Bean method with a BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor return type: Consider declaring such methods as 'static'.
2018-04-22 19:25:37.301  INFO 19474 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$98b8a232] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-04-22 19:25:37.532  INFO 19474 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-04-22 19:25:37.550  INFO 19474 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-04-22 19:25:37.550  INFO 19474 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.29
2018-04-22 19:25:37.554  INFO 19474 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
2018-04-22 19:25:37.627  INFO 19474 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-04-22 19:25:37.627  INFO 19474 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1297 ms
2018-04-22 19:25:37.682  INFO 19474 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.v.s.b.i.VaadinServletConfiguration     : Registering Vaadin servlet
2018-04-22 19:25:37.682  INFO 19474 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.v.s.b.i.VaadinServletConfiguration     : Servlet will be mapped to URLs [/vaadinServlet/*, /VAADIN/*]
2018-04-22 19:25:37.693  INFO 19474 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.v.s.b.i.VaadinServletConfiguration     : Setting servlet init parameters
2018-04-22 19:25:37.693  INFO 19474 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.v.s.b.i.VaadinServletConfiguration     : Set servlet init parameter [productionMode] = [false]
2018-04-22 19:25:37.693  INFO 19474 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.v.s.b.i.VaadinServletConfiguration     : Set servlet init parameter [resourceCacheTime] = [3600]
2018-04-22 19:25:37.693  INFO 19474 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.v.s.b.i.VaadinServletConfiguration     : Set servlet init parameter [heartbeatInterval] = [300]
2018-04-22 19:25:37.693  INFO 19474 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.v.s.b.i.VaadinServletConfiguration     : Set servlet init parameter [closeIdleSessions] = [false]
2018-04-22 19:25:37.747  INFO 19474 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-04-22 19:25:37.747  INFO 19474 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-04-22 19:25:37.747  INFO 19474 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-04-22 19:25:37.748  INFO 19474 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-04-22 19:25:37.748  INFO 19474 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
2018-04-22 19:25:37.748  INFO 19474 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2018-04-22 19:25:37.749  INFO 19474 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet springVaadinServlet mapped to [/vaadinServlet/*, /VAADIN/*]
2018-04-22 19:25:37.795  WARN 19474 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
2018-04-22 19:25:37.797  INFO 19474 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-04-22 19:25:37.809  INFO 19474 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-04-22 19:25:37.818 ERROR 19474 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:729) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:192) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1270) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1250) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at com.reminder.EJA.EjaApplication.main(EjaApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:587) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1250) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:815) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:721) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:579) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:94) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:224) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder(DataSourceProperties.java:176) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:43) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:81) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
```

This is my application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/EJA
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=database
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

And this is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.1.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.reminder'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


ext {
    vaadinVersion = '8.3.1'
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('com.vaadin:vaadin-spring-boot-starter')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "com.vaadin:vaadin-bom:${vaadinVersion}"
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the driver in your dependencies. If the driver is not in your classpath it can not be found/loaded.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    //Example
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, should I also specify version ?

Comment: Depends on whether you want to make sure that errors can not occur due to unexpected version changes